# app.post() not working with Express

Tags: node.js, post, get, express

I get a problem with Express, I try to use the app.post() function but it's not working and I don't know why...

Though I included the bodyParser()...

The problem: Page load without response, no error message. I don't see the console.log()...

app.js :

```
var express = require('express')
    , routes = require('./routes')
    , user = require('./routes/user')
    , postProvider = require('./postProvider.js')
    , http = require('http')
    , path = require('path')
    , compass = require('node-compass')
    , hash = require('./auth').hash;

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(compass());
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.cookieParser('dsqdq edsds'));
    app.use(express.session());
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('login');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    console.log('test');
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

login.jade :

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Login
  h3 "tj" and "foobar"
  form(method="post", action="/login")
    input(type="text", placeholder="Username", autofocus="true", name="username")
    br
    input(type="password", placeholder="Password", name="password")
    br
    input(type="submit", value="login")
```

Comment: Yeah,add the body-parser

Answer (score 3):

I don't find any issue with app.post code !!

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    console.log('test');
    res.end(); // end the response
});
```

One suggestion is that you should end each response send to client , otherwise your server become unresponsive.

Comment: the OP changed the jade template and now everything is O.k. :)

Comment: I found the problem but I don't understand, when I comment "app.use(compass());" it works... When I uncomment it doesn't works... What is the problem with Compass?

Comment: is `login` a page or view that you're trying to render from your `app.post()`

Comment: I had a problem with my app.post() causing my node.js server to freeze (timeout) for a while when posting too many at once. This solved it thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your post request is send to `/test` ( since you've used `action` attribute of your form ), while your express listener is listening to any post requests on `/login`.

Your code should look like :

```
block content
  h1 Login
  h3 "tj" and "foobar"
  form(method="post", action="/login")
```

If you want this to work!

Answer (score 0):

I copy 'router.post()...' to another js file,and change the route in app.js,it worked!But 'router.post()' method still a warning.sometimes it seems like a warning in webstorm,but it can actually work!

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't gone through the entire code that was mentioned here, I had found a similar issue and was able to debug it.

I'll share where I've gone wrong and maybe that might help someone.

Below code is the part of HTML which went wrong:

```
<form action="/" method="**post**">

    <select name="crypto">
        <option value="BTC">Bitcoin</option>
        <option value="ETC">Ethereum</option>
        <option value="LTC">Litecoin</option>
    </select>

    <select name="fiat">
        <option value="USD">US Dollors</option>
        <option value="GBP">GB Pounds</option>
        <option value="EUR">EU Euros</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

**Check**

Bug in this code is, Though (type) of the  is "submit", it has not been included inside  tag. Now while you use "app.post" method to get data or trying to "console.log(value)" of the requirement, it can't access.

I was able to debug by including button tag inside the form.