# nodejs post method not getting called

Tags: node.js

I found my question was asked a year ago here [app.post() not working with Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786756/app-post-not-working-with-express) but the code written there is outdated (the way bodyparser was added doesn't work anymore as well as function mentioned below) plus the asker never chose an answer so the question was never solved.

Here's my code

```
const express = require("express");
const db = require("mysql");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer"); // v1.0.5
const upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname));
console.log("before");
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server started!");
  console.log("within");
});
console.log("after");
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log("hit here in post");
  res.render("index.jade", {});
  console.log("hit here in post");
  res.json({ name: "John" });
  res.status(500).json({ error: "message" });
  res.end();
});
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index.jade", {});
  console.log("hit here in get");
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Here's the output.

```
before
after
Server started!
within
hit here in get
{}
```

I even tried to wrap the app sets and uses in app.configure like the asker of the other question to see if that was the issue but that configure function doesn't seem to exist anymore because I got an error about it.

Also I should probably note. My routing here is correct. I haven't made a views subfolder yet so that's why I have it written as it is.

**Update**

I think I may have spotted the issue but I don't understand why it's occurring. In the network tab of the browser I see that GET is getting 404 error because of a favicon.ico request but I don't understand where that request is coming from. I've seen the serve-favicon npm module to support it but didn't want to added because I never intended to add a favicon image to my server. I don't even understand how that would work.

**Reply to last comment by James**
What do you mean by I configure the middleware after it has started? Are you referring to the fact that the post method is written after port listening has started? Also if that's the reason why post isn't executing how come the get method executes regardless of that? I'm not holding back any server code aside from code I currently have commented out for the moment but that code I posted is my main index.js file and it's the only file I modified from the standard npm init project. I haven't setup any routes because I don't see the need to do so (even when I add react since my project is simple in concept of communication between reactjs, nodejs and a database "hence my frustration") which is why I'm trying to have get and post only access the root directory.

Comment: How are you making the request to the server?

Comment: How did you conclude that the method was not invoked? no console logs or error in response? I see that response status is set to `500` on purpose.

Comment: It seems that you are `GET`ing not `POST`ing

Comment: @user2263572 What do you mean? I eventually plan to have the server interact with React but at the moment I'm just trying to have the server function but itself hence why I added the jade engine.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan I copied that from somewhere. I thought it was a way of catching the error from the http request if it did hit an error but if I'm just triggering it I'll get rid of it. Thanks. Also yes I concluded that the post method doesn't execute because none of the console.log messages print in the terminal nor web console.

Comment: @codehelp4 as per the first comment, show or at least explain how you are sending the `POST` request. The only anomaly I can see is you configure the server middleware *after* it has started, probably shouldn't matter but potentially could be why the POST request never reached the server (e.g. the parser might not be setup so the POST never works). More likely to be an issue with your network request though...

Answer (score 0):

favicon is automatically requested by the browser. it is the icon used in the browser tab or url address bar

Add this, before app.get():

```
app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log({method: req.method, url: req.url});
   next();
});
```

Comment: Ok I'll add it and see if that fixes everything but I'm curious why does the browser make it a requirement to have when I'm still in the development process of the server?

Comment: It's an old standard.  Browsers will make an HTTP request for it regardless of server. It is not required to have it, but it would explain why you're seeing that GET request.

Comment: Oh ok then I assume that wouldn't be the cause of my main issue. Any idea why my post method isn't executing? (or at least doesn't appear to be since none of the log message I wrote in it are printing and the get method isn't getting the data I'm trying to post)

Comment: You can add the following:
app.all('/', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.type, req.location);  // from memory, probably wrong
     next()

});

Comment: I tried it but it didn't print anything to the output when I put it at the buttom and when I put it right below the listen function it just added a line to the output saying undefined twice.